# External Hard Disk is Not Shown in MyComputers

Tags: windows-8

I have a  Sony Laptop with Win 8.
On connecting my external HP Hard Disk of 1 TB I am unable to access it.
It is showing in Printers and Hardware.
but not shown in My-computers.

Comment: Are you able to try the drive on another computer?

Comment: Looks like a power issue, your usb port might be under powered. Use a Y cable if you have multiple usb ports on your laptop

Answer (score 1):

Try taking a look over [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/external-hdd-visible-in-devices-and-printers-but/4e550174-511c-46ab-be55-6cfb0ce54e63).

The first suggestion is what worked for the person asking for a solution;

> Method 1
>
> Check if both the external drives have drive letter assigned using
>   Disk management.
>
> a)   Open Computer Management by clicking the Start button, clicking 
>   Control Panel, clicking  System and Security, clicking Administrative
>   Tools, and then double-clicking Computer Management. If you're
>   prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>   password or provide confirmation.
>
> If both the drives does not have an drive letter then try to assign
>   letters and check if it works.
>
> To change, add, or remove a drive letter
>
> a)   Open Computer Management by clicking the Start button, clicking 
>   Control Panel, clicking  System and Security, clicking Administrative
>   Tools, and then double-clicking Computer Management. If you're
>   prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the
>   password or provide confirmation.
>
> b)   In the left pane, click Disk Management.
>
> c)    Right-click the drive that you want to change, and then click
>   Change Drive Letter and Paths.
>
> d)   Do one of the following:
>
> i. To assign a drive letter if one has not already been assigned, click Add, click the letter that you want to
>   use, and then click OK.
>
> ii. To change a drive letter, click Change, click  Assign the following drive letter, click the letter that you
>   want to use, and then click OK.
>
> iii. To remove a drive letter, click Remove and then click  Yes to confirm that you want to remove it.